# SynataxError: Unexpected Indentifier while compiling ejs file

Tags: node.js, ejs

Does anyone know what the following error is for?

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in
>   /home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/views/test.ejs while compiling ejs
>
> If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
>   https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint Or, if you meant to create an
>   async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
>       at new Function ()
>       at Template.compile (/home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:626:12)
>       at Object.compile (/home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:366:16)
>       at handleCache (/home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:215:18)
>       at tryHandleCache (/home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:16)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:459:10)
>       at View.render (/home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
>       at tryRender (/home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
>       at Function.render (/home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in
>   /home/smart/Downloads/npmPackage/views/test.ejs while compiling ejs

here is my ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <% include partials/navbar %>
    <h1>This is a test Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to put it with double quotes and have it like a function call. also you should use `<%-` for includes echo [documentation](https://ejs.co/)

Your template should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <%- include("./partials/navbar") %>
    <h1>This is a test Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't get it why I had to change the format in this, since I have been using that format in all other projects and they are working perfectly fine.

Comment: @DikshaGoyal, I think this is a legacy include, and it was removed from the latest update, checkout change log: https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md.

Comment: Oh yeah.. Thanks a ton.